# AndEngine SpriteBatch setColor() not working

Tags: java, android, sprite, andengine

I am writing a game with *AndEngine* and there I put a few dozen sprites into one *SpriteBatch*. This needs to be done, otherwise the frame rate would drop drastically when I draw every single sprite on it's own. 
My question is, how can I change the color of the complete *SpriteBatch*?

This is how I create the *SpriteBatch*:

```
ArrayList<Sprite> dozenSprites; // these are all the sprites of one SpriteBatch in a list
SpriteBatch spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(spriteBatchTextureAtlas, dozenSprites.size(),vertexBufferObjectManager);

for (Sprite sprite : dozenSprites) {
        spriteBatch.draw(sprite);
}
spriteBatch.submit();
```

Well there is nothing special about it. When everything is ready, I attach the *SpriteBatch* to my scene and it shows as it is supposed to. However, when I call `spriteBatch.setColor(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f);` nothing happens. The color only changes when I setColor(...) to every single sprite, before drawing the *SpriteBatch*  Am I doing something wrong here? Is there another way?

Every little hint is appreciated! Thank you.

**Edit: My Solution**
As *Cameron Fredmans* suggested (thanks again!) I first tried to extend the `SpriteBatch class`directly and implement the `setColor()`method. But I couldn't figure out how, so I chose the quick and dirty variant:

```
 // initialize the SpriteBatch as above
 // and to change the color call:
 spriteBatch.reset();
 for (Sprite sprite : dozenSprites) {
        sprite.setColor( theNewColor );
        spriteBatch.draw(sprite);
 }
 spriteBatch.submit();
```

Using a spriteBatch brings so much more performance, that keeping the ArrayList with all the original sprites and reinitializing the batch every time is still fast enough for me. But of course I would be very interested when someone succeeds in extending the SpriteBatch class! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although SpriteBatch has a setColor(), that's really just an artifact of it extending Shape. Two possible solutions:

**(1) Color each sprite individually.**

```
ArrayList<Sprite> dozenSprites; // these are all the sprites of one SpriteBatch in a list
SpriteBatch spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(spriteBatchTextureAtlas, dozenSprites.size(),vertexBufferObjectManager);

for (Sprite sprite : dozenSprites) {
        sprite.setColor(.5f, .5f, .5f);
        spriteBatch.draw(sprite);
}
spriteBatch.submit();
```

**(2) Modify SpriteBatch in AndEngine**

If you really don't want to color each sprite, how about modifying the SpriteBatch class in AndEngine and add a method that overrides setColor().  Add a color field to the spritebatch, have the setcolor adjust that field, and then, in the draw method, have the spritebatch set the color of the sprite it's drawing to its stored color field.

If you implement it cleanly in AndEngine, you could even submit it as a possible change for the source.  (It's open source.  Fun to get involved.)

Comment: thanks! I will try to figure out how to modify the spritebatch so it has a color field. If I can't i might have to use (1).. but at least I know where I stand now, thank you.